# Counting the transition in a dataframe overtime

Tags: data-science-model

I am stuck at a problem and am thinking how to come out of it. I want to write a code in python with dataframe as below:

data = {'Id':['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
        'value':['Active', 'Notactive', 'Active', 'Superactive', 'Notactive', 'Superactive'],
        'date':['8-09-2019','15-09-2019','8-09-2019','15-09-2019','8-09-2019','15-09-2019']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
I want to reach to the result where i count the number of users who did transition in the 7 day difference:
Active to notactive: 1
Active to superactive: 1
Not active to superactive: 1
Active to Active: 0

Any help on how to proceed would be appreciated on python 3.7

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a small dataset try this:

```py
# change type of date column so that it is possible to find min and max correctly
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# put value of the oldest resord and newest record side by side
df_min_max_grouped = pd.merge(
    df.loc[df.groupby('Id')['date'].idxmin()],
    df.loc[df.groupby('Id')['date'].idxmax()],
    on='Id',
    suffixes=('_old', '_new')
)

# group by old value and new value and find counts
results = df_min_max_grouped.groupby(['value_old', 'value_new']).size()

results
```

Output:

```
value_old  value_new  
Active     Notactive      1
           Superactive    1
Notactive  Superactive    1
dtype: int64
```

The approach I chose for this answer:

1. Convert `date` values to be of type `datetime`, Correct ordering will not work with string dates.
2. First find the oldest and the newest records for any `Id`,
   This happens in : `df.loc[df.groupby("Id")['date'].idxmin()]` for oldest and `df.loc[df.groupby("Id")['date'].idxmax()]` and newest records.
3. Join the oldest and newest records on the basis of `Id`, and then
4. Group by old `value` and new `value` combination to get a count in each group.

I found that resetting index of the resulting `Series` produces nice output:

```py
results.reset_index()
```

|  | value_old | value_new | 0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Active | Notactive | 1 |
| 1 | Active | Superactive | 1 |
| 2 | Notactive | Superactive | 1 |

The combinations not listed here have 0 records against them. I hope you find this helpful!

Comment: @Iytseeker thanks for the response. It is a perfect script to give the necessary output.

Thanks,